# How to specify a different shape in a legend in HTML?

Tags: html, legend

I am able to create a legend for colors by specifying the background-color using the legend in HTML. Each entry in the legend is in a rectangular shape.

However, I want to create a legend for shapes (e.g. circle, ellipse, triangle, etc) in HTML, but I didn’t find a way to specify a different shape other than a rectangle in the legend.

I am wondering if there is a way to specify a different shape other than a rectangle in the legend in HTML?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

EDITs:

Resolved by using https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Sure, use CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/y58833ms/

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up terms. An HTML shape is an image-map, with clickable areas attached to an image or graphic.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_shape.asp

Generally people use CSS, SVG or graphic images to create shapes in HTML.

You can use CSS to create shapes in HTML using an attribute to represent a square, circle, star and many other shapes.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Another alternative is SVG where you can create any shape or animation. SVG has some shapes built in or you can create your own shapes and be as complicated as needed. For instance, you might use SVG to create an image of character like Homer Simpson (http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg)

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_rect.asp

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions! I used https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ and it works. This is really helpful! Thank you very much again!